# MSTest - Visual Studio Team Services - Selenium - Unable to get the results back after running a test suite

Tags: azure, selenium-webdriver, tfs, visual-studio-2015, azure-devops

I am running a Selenium test in a distributed fashion and there is a lot of tests. Around 5000 tests.

I am able to see all the test are completed and at the end, I am not able to see the test results from build agent getting transferred and see the results in the web interface.

The build never completes. But the trx file is generated in the build agent.

All, I can see is below screenshot.

[image]

I believe this is because of the images which I attach to the test result in case of failure. The images are quite big and for each of the failed test I am attaching many images ( screenshots )

Can any Microsoft guys please answer if I am correct. After a long wait ( 1 hr) , I cancelled the build and I am able to see results displayed for 2000 test ( on a total of 4100 tests)

I am also clueless why it stopped at 2000?

Is there a limitiation of trx file size, it is 21GB ( including the folder with sreenshots )

[image]

Please help.

Comment: Does this issue always occur? Can you share the logs under buildagent\_diag when this issue occur?

Comment: For the number of test result, you may refer to these links for details: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/77f65607-b10e-407f-b744-81baeea88473/publishing-more-than-2500-test-results?forum=tfsbuild  &    https://github.com/Microsoft/vso-agent/issues/90